# Does Solana plan to integrate ECDSA to it's signing algos?

Tags: transactions

Does Solana plan to integrate ECDSA to it's signing algos ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no plans to move away from ed25519 or support a new signing algo.

There is, however, very limited support for ecrecover for secp256k1 signatures through a native program: https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#secp256k1-program